# how to fix not displaying form widget in html

Tags: django

i'm new in django. I need to create the form widget as an input to push the data from input to script. The problem is that my form does not display and I have no idea where is the mistake. My goal is to get data from input so it will be found in database api and saved in my db. Appreciate for advice.

views.py

```
 def data(request):
        url = 'http://www.omdbapi.com/?t={}&apikey=My key is here'

        if request.method == 'POST':
            form = MovieForm(request.POST)
            form.save()

        form = MovieForm()
        movies = Movie.objects.all() #// fetch all objects
        movies_data = []  #//// array for movies and their details
        for movie in movies:
            r = requests.get(url.format(movie)).json() #// gets details from api

            movies_main = {
                'title': movie.title,
                'director': r['Director'],
                'rate': r['imdbRating'],
            }
            movies_data.append(movies_main)
        context = {'movies_data':movies_data}
        return render(request, 'movies/movies.html', context)
```

forms.py

```
from django.forms import ModelForm, TextInput
    from .models import Movie

    class MovieForm(ModelForm):
        class Meta:
            model = Movie
            fields = ['title']
            widgets = {'title' : TextInput(attrs={'class' : 'id', 'placeholder' : 'put your id' })}
```

models.py

```
from django.db import models

# Create your models here.
class Movie(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=50)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = 'movies'
```

template

```
    {% load static %}
        <html>
        <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="{%static 'movies/style.css' %}">
        <script type="text/javascript">

        </script>
        </head>

        <body>
            <div class='container'>
                <header>Movies API</header>
                    <form method="POST" action='/index'>  
                        {% csrf_token %}
                        {{ form.title }}
                        <input type='submit' class='sub', value='add'> 
                    </form>
            </div>
        </body>
        </html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Form` is not shown in template, because it is not passed in template context for rendering. Let's try like this.

## views.py

```
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect
def data(request):
    url = 'http://www.omdbapi.com/?t={}&apikey=My key is here'
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = MovieForm(data=request.POST)
        form.save()
        return HttpResponseRedirect(request.get_full_path()) # During HTTP POST processing, refresh page (Or change with your logic in future).
    else:
        form = MovieForm()
        movies = Movie.objects.all() #// fetch all objects
        movies_data = []  #//// array for movies and their details
        for movie in movies:
            r = requests.get(url.format(movie)).json() #// gets details from api
            movies_main = {
                'title': movie.title,
                'director': r['Director'],
                'rate': r['imdbRating'],
            }
            movies_data.append(movies_main)
    context = {
        'form': form,
        'movies_data': movies_data,
    }
    return render(request, 'movies/movies.html', context)
```

## your template

```
{% load static %}
        <html>
        <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="{%static 'movies/style.css' %}">
        <script type="text/javascript">

        </script>
        </head>

        <body>
            <div class='container'>
                <header>Movies API</header>
                    <form method="POST" action='/index'>  
                        {% csrf_token %}
                        <!-- you also can use {#% form.as_p %#} or {#% form.as_table %#}, but form.title is fine also. -->
                        {{ form.title }}
                        <input type='submit' class='sub', value='add' /> 
                    </form>
            </div>
        </body>
        </html>
```

Comment: you are a star ! thaks very much :)